# C# AssemblyVersion 3 digits for use with NuGet's PreRelease versioning

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Will generates a `1.0.x.x` four digits version number.

Which, if I use this nuspec metadata:

```
<version>$version$-test</version>
```

generates an error when packing:

```
The version « 1.0.5431.31092-test » does not follow semantic version control instructions
```

Is there a simple way around this?

Comment: What do you mean "three digits one"? Clearly `Assembly.GetName().Version` has 4 parts (due to being `System.Version`)... so you probably mean something different, but unclear what.

Comment: Ok I get this now. The class has a three digits constructor but its properties are not nullable. That makes sens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, an assembly's version is stored in the System.Version class, that consists of Major, Minor, Build and Revision.

EDIT: I was a bit to hasty to answer. When you use the AssemblyVersionAttribute's constructor with a string containing an asterix, all four properties of a version will be generated. The only way to cause a version with lesser numbers is to specify the exact version number, without asterix, i.e "1.0.1". See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

What you could do, if you want lesser numbers in the version and also generated version numbers, is to use an external tool altering version numbers in the pre-build step.

Comment: the class has a three digits constructor, and the ToString() method even returns a three digits version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00dkw4kk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're correct, I was mixing up System.Version and the behaviour of AssemblyVersionAttribute. If you use "1.0.x" in AssemblyVersionAttribute's constructor, both Build and Revision will be generated. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Still, your answer helped me understand. It's an object not a string

Comment: Even if I set "1.0.1", NuGet sees "1.0.1.0" which makes sens since Version is an object with non nullable int members, so "1.0.1.0-test" still generate an error beacue of the extra digit.

Comment: @Jerther Why did you mark this as an answer to your question? It does not solve the problem at all, and is in fact incorrect: nuget will still get 4 digits even if a 3 digit version is specified in the `AssemblyVersion`. I created a [new question about the number of digits issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194498/nuget-pack-does-not-honor-number-of-digits-on-assembly-version) which I feel is the core problem that would also solve your issue here if fixed.

Comment: `What you could do, if you want lesser numbers in the version and also generated version numbers, is to use an external tool altering version numbers in the pre-build step.` This would not help at all. Even if the attribute has only 3 explicit digits, the nuget parsing process seem to always use all 4 digits.

Comment: An external tool works. I made one that reads the assembly version which always has four digits and only take the first three and put it in the nuspec.

Answer (score 1):

No post processing is necessary, `NuGet` is using `[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("")]` as a package version, set it to whatever number of componets you please and be done with it.

**P.S** I strongly encourage you to also set `AssemblyVersion` as this is the one .NET actually uses, at least set it to auto increment

Some reading [available here](https://codingforsmarties.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/how-to-version-assemblies-destined-for-nuget/)

Full example

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0")]
```

Will generate a package `Lib.1.0.nupkg` containing assembly with 1.0.x.x version, version you will be dealing with is `1.0`

Whenever you want to change nuget version, just change `AssemblyInformationalVersion`, not touch `AssemblyVersion` at all

Comment: You can add the -test postfix :

[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0-test")]